# Microsoft Device client too heavy for Windows FormAplicattion

Tags: c#, winforms, azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

OS: Windows10

SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Devices v1.3.2

Language: C#

Hello, I´m developing a Windows Form Application on C#. In this app, I´m sending messages to my IoT Hub using the NuGet Packet **Microsoft.Azure.Devices v1.3.2** and receive those messages on a raspberry pi.
Ony with this package install, the app is about 30 MB, and that´s ok for me.
The problem is that I need to receive messages from the IoT Hub in this app too, so what I did is to install the NuGetPacket **Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client v1.5.0** that help me receive messages, but if I install this package, it increases the weight of the app like 300 MB more, and that´s way to heavier than I want it.

My question is, is there other way to receive message from my IoT Hub in my Windows Form Application without all that extra weight? Am I missing a package to help me do that in a more easy way?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hmya, these Nuget packages have to keep entirely too many possible platform targets happy.  Everything and the kitchen-sink is included, .NETStandard is not nearly standard enough yet.  Focus on what you actually find back in your project's build directory.  Those 300 megabytes get whittled down to ~22 MB when I try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use EventHubClient to receive message from Azure IoT Hub, which is in [WindowsAzure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus). WindowsAzure.ServiceBus has no dependencies, it is about 3M. And more, you can get the sample source code from [azure-iot-sdk-csharp](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp). The tool of DeviceExplorer use EventHubClient to receive message.

There are so much dependencies about Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client v1.5.0. When you use nuget to install Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client, the dependencies will be installed too. After building your project, you can find the *.dll libraries in you output directory. If you want to reduce package's capacity, can remove some *.dll which are not used, such as localization libraries, but it is not recommended. In fact, all of the dependencies are about 20M, why the weight of your app increased to 300M maybe some other reason.

[image: dependencies]